# how to make condition statement after dot(.) or before property in any method or class

Tags: dart

how to make condition statement after dont(.) or before property  in any method  or class

for example i have the following

```
bool a = true ;

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
            .limit(10)
            .where('visible', isEqualTo: true) // here i need to use a? isEqualTo : whereIn
    
             {.............}
```

or at least

```
a?.where('visible', isEqualTo: true) : .where('visible', whereIn: [1])
```

what is the best way to do it instead of making condition to the whole parent

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax supporting choosing between two different methods to call on the same receiver inside one expression.

Either:

```dart
var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
            .limit(10);
query = a 
  ? query.where('visible', isEqualTo: true)
  : query.where('visible', whereIn: [1]);
query....the rest...
```

Alternatively, maybe, since the method you're calling uses optional parameters, it might accept `null` as equivalent to not passing an argument.
In that case:

```dart
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
      .limit(10)
      .where('visible', isEqualTo: a ? true : null, whereIn: a ? null : [1])
      ...the rest ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i will use the last part in your answer . really thanks Irn